# Question on LED current and voltage

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, led, current, gpio

This is regarding this [battery charger IC.](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP73871-Data-Sheet-20002090E.pdf)

In the below image, the output low voltage on the STATx pin is given as 1V, but that is for 4mA of sink current. That translates to around 0.25ohm of internal resistance/impedance.

[image]

If the LED's forward current (LEDs connected to the STAT pins) is higher than the 4mA, then subsequently, the maximum output voltage on the STAT pins, would increase. How high can the output voltage go or be?
Just want to understand how this works if the LED current is higher.

Comment: Should be no different than how a pull down MOSFET  behaves. Just a source-drain resistance that also increases with temperature.

Comment: The data sheet doesn't appear to give other information on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's telling you about the output of the pin. The output isn't going to be a simple resistor, but it'll be something else, like a MOSFET or similar, with an open drain. 
So what it's saying is how low it can drive its output, and how much current it can sink.

If you want to use it with an LED, then look at the datasheet, page 2, typical appliction circuit you can see how you should use these pins if you want to use an LED. To turn the LED on, it drives the voltage of the pin low, and sinks current through the LED. 
Lets say you want to use HLMP-1700 from broadcom, a red LED. Forward voltage is 1.7V, max current is 10mA. The STATT pin can definietly sink 10mA as that's less than its 16mA typical. So we just need to figure out our series resistor, assuming you're using a 5V, you do 5V, minus 1.7V for the diode, minus 0.4V for the statt pin
5 - 1.7 - 0.4 = 2.9V 
then with a known current and voltage you calculate your series resistance to be 
2.3V / 10mA = 289 Ohms. You might choose a 330Ohm resistor as that'll be more available, and it's better to have slightly less than maximum current than slightly more.

Say you want to use L-53HD from kindbright instead, a brighter LED.
Forward voltage is 2.25V, but the recomended forward current is 20mA. This it between the typical rating of 16mA and the maximum rating of 35mA. You could still use this LED, but you might find that it doesn't light quite as brightly as you might expect, and you might find a difference between pins, or different boards if you make more than one.

Answer (score 1):

> That translates to around 0.25ohm of internal resistance/impedance.`

No, 0.25 **k**Ohms. Divide millivolts by milliamps to get ohms. So the typical would be 400mV/4mA = 100 Ohms.

As for your main question, I'd say two things:

1. 4 mA is fairly enough for general indication purposes, unless you really want to illuminate something or blind the user. So I wouldn't worry about currents above that level. [This app note](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/01260B.pdf) demonstrates indication for about 5 mA (for red LEDs i.e. lowest Vf drop of 2V), for example.
2. The datasheet doesn't give any further information so it's almost impossible to make any assumptions here. Personally, I wouldn't expect a drop of higher than 1V across the entire sink current range. Otherwise it gets ridiculous.